# How to stress cpu with a single php script running?

Tags: php, load, xampp, cpu, primes

i've made a little script to calculate prime numbers, i'm using the latest xampp (x86) on win7 (x64) and the script used about 25% of cpu and completed on 2min, i've tried the latest wampserver (x64) and using the same 25% of cpu it somehow takes more than double the time to finish. on both xampp and wampserver, when i open the same file a lot of times it keeps on 25%, if i make 4 different files with the same script but different names and open all 4 the cpu goes to 100% and the temps increase pretty much the same as running prime 95.

i would like to do this prime number calculations in a way that it would take 100% of the cpu (or a bit less if not possible) running a single script, any ideas?

i will start learning c++ and for this kind of stuff i think it would be better suited but i know php and i would like to do it using it, maybe later i will do the same or better but using c++.

i think it's not possible not even heard of something like this but if i could run two blocks of code simultaneosly on the same php script maybe it would do the trick (or not considering that this seems to me like a pretty 'artificial' limit that can be 'set/removed', i may be wrong so hear your opinions on this will be good).

also, any theories on why is wampserver so slow compared to xampp (both with nothing more installed and both with default settings), also some good tips to speed them up would be nice, i mean, wamp should at least be able to keep up more or less with xampp(there isn't a big difference on the stuff one installs and the other)?

Comment: You can maybe tweak your php.ini to allow php use more memory and things like that so that it will take a lot of CPU.

Comment: You use a quad core CPU or a dual core with HT? A single process will (and can) only run on exactly one core, meaning: You need at least as many processes as cores you have

Comment: You can't load more than one core with one thread. I'm guessing you have a CPU with four cores, so you need either 4 processes, or a process with 4 threads (or 2 with 2).

Comment: @KingCrunch A single *thread* will (and can) only run on exactly one core, meaning: You need at least as many *threads* as cores you have - since PHP does not support multi-threading this equates to the same thing in this case, but it's best to be correct...

Comment: @KingCrunch quadcore, and the load it's distributed 25% for each core, at least that's what the task manager reports. also a lot of running php scripts with the same name don't make it pass 25%, but if i change the names and execute 4 scripts with the different names it gets to 100% as i said on my question

Comment: @Mat only one script is already using the 4 cores but at 25% (at least so the taskmanager says)

Comment: @wxiiir: the OS scheduler will run your one script on whatever core it thinks is best whenever it schedules. You script is moved from core to core seemingly randomly because of other events that happen on your system. (You can try playing with the CPU affinity in the task manager I think.) One single-threaded process cannot run on two different cores at any one time.

Comment: @lc2817 it won't cut it because if the php script exhausts the memory it tells me that it did (i have the limit set to 128mb) and if i try to compute the prime numbers to 50million (to test the memory limit that the script uses) it will warn me that it exhausted those 128mb so that's probably not the problem

Comment: @Mat i've tried already, unless you know of any way to know and alter xampp cpu-affinity win7 will not let me even touch it. and what you say is probably right but it isn't the only thing that's happening for sure because if opened 4 instances of the same script then it would max out, and it doesn't, only if i open 4 instances of the same script with different name

Comment: @DaveRandom: First of all I wrote "processes" and not "threads", even if you can keep multiple cores busy with threads too, of course. However, in PHP you can use `pctnl_fork()` to create process forks, that then can run on separate cores. Or you can use `proc_open()` to create sub processes directly

Comment: @KingCrunch you gave me an excellent idea, maybe if i kinda "distribute" the work that has to be done for 4 processes using a main php script it will do it, even if it doesn't work for sure it will come in handy ;)

Comment: @wxiiir thank for having made the test and sending feedacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To max out the server you need to increase the max execution time of php to something really big but I also suggest to run the script from the command line because apache can make a big difference. Try running lighttpd with fast-cgi it makes a big difference.

Comment: all that helped a bit on the speed of the execution of the script itself, which is good for me too by the way because it's a script that really needs speed, but what i really need and will be doing is to distribute the work for 4 separate processes to max out all cores. thank you